# Generate a sprite from bitmap in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, flashdevelop

I am very new to Flex and Action Script 3.  I am trying to write a simple function that will copy a rectangular area from a loaded bitmap, and generate a sprite for it. I just want to learn how to copy part of an image to another.

The function is :

```
public static function GenerateSprite(x:int,y:int,w:int,h:int)
{
var bt:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
var mtx:Matrix = new Matrix();
mtx.translate(-x, -y);
bt.draw(bitmap, mtx, null, null, null, null);
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bt, null, false, false);
s.graphics.endFill;
return s;
}
```

x,y,w, and h represent the x,y location of the sprite, its width and height respectively.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

yours sincerely

PS: I am using FlashDevelop for this.

Comment: `s.graphics.endFill` is an expression of type Function, not a call to the function :) to call use braces after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `copyPixels` here, and you need a parameter bitmap for the source bitmap, and a function return value `Sprite`.

Here is my fix for you:

```
public static function GenerateSprite(bitmap:Bitmap,x:int,y:int,w:int,h:int):Sprite
{
    var bt:BitmapData = new BitmapData( w, h );
    bt.copyPixels( bitmap.bitmapData, new Rectangle(x,y,w,h), new Point(0,0) );
    var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
    s.graphics.beginBitmapFill( bt, null, false, true );
    s.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, w, h );
    s.graphics.endFill();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Add `s.graphics.lineStyle(0,0,0);` before `drawRect`, otherwise the black outline will spoil the effect.